# Проблема с передачей состояния на сервер

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net, jquery

У меня такая проблема: использую иструменты ***jQuery UI***, чтобы показать диалог.
Для этого у меня есть отдельный **div**, куда я кинул **UpdatePanel** и **TextBox**. Но когда идёт обращение на сервер (при нажатии на триггер), то этот **TextBox** пустой (**TextBox.Text.Equals(String.Empty)**), как будто **EnableViewState == false**. Убирал **UpdatePanel** из **div**, ставил в другое место, всё работает, значит c **TextBox** что-то делает **jQuery**. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery выносит элементы диалога за пределы DOM поэтому и не получается узнать состояние элементов на прямую не получиться. Надо искать обходной путь. И я его нашёл :)

Comment: Было бы интересно посмотреть примеры кода, как вы подружили jQuery UI, ajax и asp.net.